# localStorage is not defined in custom hook (Next js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, local-storage

I have this custom useLocalStorage hook, which works fine with create-react-app, but with Next js it returns undefined in the value init state on line 3.

How can I bypass SSR to always have access to LocalStorage? Or I guess the real question is how do I set state with access to localStorage outside a useEffect?

```js
const useLocalStorage = (storageKey, fallbackState) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageKey)) ?? fallbackState,
    )

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem(storageKey, JSON.stringify(value))
    }, [value, storageKey])

    return [value, setValue]
}
```

Comment: I think you just need to check if window is defined first. I think you are just running into the server side rendering issue where there isn't a window so there isn't a local storage yet. So check if window, then run your code should work fine.

Comment: Thanks Colin, doing this within useState() works:
typeof window !== 'undefined' ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageKey)) ?? fallbackState : '',

Comment: While that may solve the immediate error, it will cause hydration mismatches due to Next.js SSR. You shouldn't initialise a state variable based on `localStorage` (or any client-side-only API for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation of useLocalStorage (I have used it in several projects):

```
// useLocalStorage.js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

export default function useLocalStorage(
    key
    initialValue
) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
        if (typeof localStorage !== "undefined") {
            const jsonValue = localStorage.getItem(key)
            if (jsonValue != null) return JSON.parse(jsonValue)
        }

        if (typeof initialValue === "function") {
            return initialValue()
        } else {
            return initialValue
        }
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value))
    }, [prefixedKey, value])

    return [value, setValue]
}
```